# JQuery Error Trying to Make Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sharepoint-2010

I'm working on a SharePoint project.  I would like to use JQuery to make an ajax call from the home page.  However, when I make the call I get **"Array.prototype.slice: 'this' is not a JavaScript object " error.**

Here are the files ad code that I'm using:
homepage.js/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   Ajax.GetWeather();
});
```

Ajax.js/

```
    ns.GetWeather = function () {
   alert("yep");
    $.ajax({
        data: $.extend({
            Function: "GetWeather"
        }),
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (json) {

            //$('#ContentMain').append(json.LoginMainHtml);
            //$('#ContentSide').append(json.LoginSideHtml);
            alert("hmmmm");
            ns.HideUpdateStatus();
        }
    });
};
```

14/TEMPLATYS/LAYOUTS/GWR/Ajax.ashx/

```
    <%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="ajax" %>

     using System;
     using System.Reflection;
     using System.Web;

     /**
     * Ajax.ashx
     * 
     * Enables client callback resource to client javascript.
     * Functions are relayed to DataManager for processing.
     */
     public class ajax : IHttpHandler 
     {
      /// <summary>
      /// Processes the client request
      /// </summary>
      public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) 
      {
        // Set the content type so the client's browser will handle the response correctly
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/json";

        // Get the function name from the request GET/POST parameters
        string function = context.Request["Function"];
   context.Response.Write(function);
}
    }
```

DataManager.cs/

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web;

namespace GWR
{
  class DataManager: Util
  {

    #region Properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Accesses the Request object
    /// </summary>
    private static HttpRequest Context
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.Request; }
    }
    #endregion


    #region GetWeather
    public static string GetWeather()
    {
        return ToJson(new
        {
            //LoginSideHtml = RenderUserControl("LoginSide.ascx", null),
            //LoginMainHtml = RenderUserControl("LoginMain.ascx", null)
            AlertHTML = "<h1>Got Here Alert Weather</h1>",
            CurrentHTML = "<h2>Got here current weather",
            FiveDayHTML = "<h3>5 day forcast</h3>"

        });
    }

    #endregion

    #region ToJson
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts an object into JSON compatible form
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="o"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string ToJson(object o)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        return serializer.Serialize(o);
    }
    #endregion
  }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
data: $.extend({
        Function: "GetWeather"
    })
```

should be:

```
data: $.extend({},{
        "Function": "GetWeather"
     })
```

or:

```
data: {"Function":"GetWeather"}
```

or:

```
data: "Function=GetWeather"
```